# How to display dropdown selected value in pdf using ReactToPrint plugin?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

After select dropdown value when i click print link that time open window for save pdf but not display dropdown selected value and always display first value

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-x6ibe

How display dropdown selected value on print link click using ReactToPrint plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is re-rendering the select element for the print view, but since it is an uncontrolled component it may just be reverting to default unselected value state.  If you're trying to print whatever the selected value is you can add an `onChange` handler to save the value to the parent state to render into a printable div.

[image: Edit react-to-print]

Comment: I need selected value with dropdown view in pdf(like window.print() view dropdown) and not display set state label value in pdf

Comment: @Veera do you mind updating your question then to reflect and state your actual expected result? As asked, this solution displays the selected value via the print link/button.

Comment: If i selected "bbbbbbb" in dropdown and click pdf link that time this link (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-x6ibe)  pdf view is proper but in pdf all time display first value "aaaaaa" which is wrong . if i selected "bbbbbb" that time display "bbbbbbb" value in pfd dropdown.

I need solution for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

copy this and post in the index

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";

class Selector extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.props.onChange}>
          <option>aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
          <option>bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentToPrint extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Selected Option: [{this.props.children}]</div>;
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    option: ''
  };

  handaleSelaction = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ option: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Selector onChange={this.handaleSelaction} />

        <ComponentToPrint ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)}>
          {this.state.option}
        </ComponentToPrint>

        <ReactToPrint
          trigger={() => <a href="/#">Print</a>}
          content={() => this.componentRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

this is [show in the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-q56tm)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-x6ibe

I need selected value with dropdown view in pdf(like window.print() view dropdown) and not display set state label value in pdf

Comment: I need proper solution. Not before answer code copy and paste in replay.